# Give a repeated field of a ProtocolBuffer message into a custom list adapter

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf message of type OrderList

```
message OrderList {
  repeated Order orders = 1;
}
```

I want to pass this list of orders into a custom adapter that I wrote.

```
void guiUpdateOrders(final OrderList new_order_list) {
  setListAdapter(new OrderRowAdapter(OrderActivity.this, R.layout.order_row, 
            (ArrayList<Order>) new_order_list.getOrdersList()));
}
```

But when I do this, I get the following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList
```

Comment: Umm, what does `getOrdersList()` actually return?

Comment: For a protobuf message of type OrderList, getOrdersList() returns List<Order>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird that the `ListView` wants a modifiable copy of the `List` to be supplied to the adapter.

Can you try giving it what it wants?

```
 setListAdapter(new OrderRowAdapter(OrderActivity.this, R.layout.order_row, 
        new ArrayList(new_order_list.getOrdersList())));
```